# How to check number of Dataproc clusters in use at any given time in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataproc

How to check number of Dataproc clusters in use at any given time in Google Cloud Platform ?
If Yes,we need the way to Visualize that in GCP as well .

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the Cloud Dataproc in a project with [`gcloud dataproc clusters list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/list). This command can also filter the clusters by status, label, etc. For your case, the filtered command should look like the following:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters list \
    --filter='status.state = RUNNING'
```

You can also list all the clusters in a project and a certain region [with the Dataproc API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/list). The `projects.regions.clusters.list` method also accepts filters. The documentation I linked for the API method has a list of the available filters, the `gcloud` command also uses those same filters.

For other monitoring options, check the [Stackdriver monitoring for Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/stackdriver-monitoring)

Comment: This will give all the running state clusters .but our requirement to get the list of specific clusters which are in running state but they are not being used from quite some time.

Comment: @DataVishesh With the `gcloud` command you can filter the clusters by `status`. For example `status.state = RUNNING` I'll update the answer to make the information clearer.

Comment: Can we setup an alert mechanism on top of it .

Comment: @DataVishesh There's no build in alert that I'm aware of. In any case, it should be possible to automate a script that runs the command and reads the output. You can evaluate the result and trigger the alert you need. Also, if my answer was helpful, remember that you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It will add visibility to the answer and help other users with your same question

Answer (score 0):

Your comment on previous answer `our requirement to get the list of specific clusters which are in running state but they are not being used from quite some time` makes me think that your end goal is to delete unused clusters. One way to automate this is to use Scheduled Deletion feature [1], which can auto delete unused clusters after a period of inactivity.

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ... --max-idle=2d
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scheduled-deletion

Comment: Yes .You can help us finding clusters which are not used after a long period of time.?